# Period of continued fraction expansion and class number

Tags: nt.number-theory, continued-fractions

Let $d>1$ be not a square. Then the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt d$ is $[a_0; \overline{a_1,\dots,a_\ell}]$, where $a_0=\lfloor \sqrt d\rfloor$ and $a_\ell=2a_0$.
Thus, $\ell=\ell(d)$.

About 30 years ago I heard a talk where $\ell(d)$ was somehow related to the class number of $\mathbb Q(d)$ -- in particular, to [the Gauss class number problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_number_problem) which conjectures that there are infinitely many natural $d$ for which class number is 1.

Unfortunately, I don't remember how to restate this conjecture via $\ell(d)$. Any reference would be helpful.

Comment: Should $a_0=\lfloor d \rfloor$ be $a_0=\bigl\lfloor \sqrt d\,\bigr \rfloor$?

Comment: This should go via Pell's equation: if you want a fundamental unit for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ then this amounts to solving $T^2-dU^2=1$, and this reduces to computing a continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt{d}$. Then the regulator of the field should give a connection back to class number.

Comment: Yes, Joe. Fixed.

Comment: @StiofánFordham What's the regulator of the field?

Comment: For real quadratic fields, the regulator is just the logarithm of the fundamental unit. It is one of the quantities involved in [Dirichlet's class number formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_number_formula#Dirichlet_class_number_formula), class number itself of course being another.

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks!

Comment: The deleted answer of Henri Cohen contains a reference https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438686/ which is useful for real fields also: "one is able to express, for a prime $p$ of form $4m − 1$, $p > 3$, the class number of the quadratic ﬁeld of discriminant $−p$ in terms of the period of the continued fraction for $p^{1/2}$ <i>whenever the class number of the quadratic ﬁeld of discriminant $4p$ is one.</i>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claude Levesque, [On semi-reduced quadratic forms, continued fractions and class number](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Ekyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/0998-7.pdf), quotes a theorem of Lu, H., On the class number of real quadratic fields, Scientia Sinica II (special number, 1979), 118-130, as follows:

Let $m>1$ be a squarefree integer. Then the class number of ${\bf Q}(\sqrt m)$ is one if and only if $$\theta+\sum_{i=1}^{\ell}k_i=\lambda_1(m)+\lambda_2(m)$$ where $\omega=(1+\sqrt m)/2$ if $m\equiv1\bmod4$, otherwise $\omega=\sqrt m$, the continued fraction for $\omega$ is $[k_0,\overline{k_1,\dots,k_{\ell}}]$, $\theta$ is zero, one, or two depending on $m\bmod4$ and the parity of $\ell$ and $k_{\ell/2}$, and $\lambda_1(m)$ (respectively, $\lambda_2(m)$) is the number of solutions in nonnegative integers of $x^2+4yz=\Delta$ (respectively, $x^2+4y^2=\Delta$), where $\Delta$ is $m$ if $m\equiv1\bmod4$, otherwise $4m$.

For the detailed definition of $\theta$, see the paper of Levesque. The paper goes on to prove related results.

Another paper that may be relevant is Louboutin, Mollin, & Williams, Class Numbers of Real Quadratic Fields, Continued Fractions, Reduced Ideals, Prime-Producing Quadratic Polynomials and Quadratic Residue Covers, Canadian Journal of Mathematics 44 (1992) 824-842. DOI:10.4153/CJM-1992-049-0.